# Add a field to a JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How do you add a field to a json in javascript?
I've seen it done with arrays but I need it with a JSON field.

So basically

```
{
   "hello":"this is cool"
}
```

into

```
{
   "hello":"this is cool",
   "hi":"i know"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so

```js
const json = {
   "hello":"this is cool"
};

json['hi'] = "i know";

console.log(json);
```

If JSON is a string you can use JSON.parse() as per [MDN web docs JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: JSON is always and only a string. Otherwise you have a JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it to **JSON**, then you can do it like below.

```js
let json = `{
  "key": "value"
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.website = "Stack Overflow";

json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
```

However, if you want to do it to a regular **object**, just simply run the code below.

```js
const obj = {
  key: "value",
};

obj.website = "Stack Overflow";
console.log(obj);
```